# ZF2 segment route: only last element

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework-routing

I have this segment route:

```
'content' => array(
    'type'    => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/:title{-}-:id',
        'constraints' => array(
            'title'         => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'id'            => '[0-9]+',
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller'    => 'content',
            'action'        => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),
```

And it properly recognize an url like this, with "id=20":

```
http://example.com/blood-on-ice-20
```

but it recognize "id=20" also with this url:

```
http://example.com/timekeeper-20th-anniversary-box-12951
```

how can I avoid this?

Comment: Are you sure that the above code is the one you tested, since for the last url I got 12951 as my id value?

Comment: @NextDeveloper the complete code is this: https://gist.github.com/Gamempire/099ddfa1e8ed5b0e5d1c

Comment: Your route pattern is not really good as it can leads to this sort of error. You should use something more discriminating, like ```/:title{-}/:id```

Comment: There are no other ways?